# Android Permission Settings: How to highlight 'All The Time' row item

Tags: android, location, android-permissions

I see some apps are able to highlight / flash "All the time" row item when opening the Location Permissions Settings screen.

How to achieve this behavior?

[image].

Comment: Have never encountered it. Does this happen on stock android/emulator/some custom rom? can you give example of such app?

Comment: I think I've seen Uber do it